# Server was unable to process request.,Object reference not set to an instance of an object. SOAP API

Tags: soap

want to push data through soap API, code provided in API documentation is given below. i am getting error. error i am getting. let me know where i am wrong, thanks in advance.
[url](http://122.15.126.33/IPRU_PFA_Vendor_Data/Service.asmx)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <PushData xmlns="RBSS">
        <RBSS>
        <Lead_Response_DateTime>20-05-2016 10:25:16</Lead_Response_DateTime>
        <Lead_Push_DateTime>20-05-2016 10:25:16</Lead_Push_DateTime>
        <Lead_Recd_DataTime>20-05-2016 10:25:16</Lead_Recd_DataTime>
        <FirstName>test</FirstName>
        <Phone1>9876543215</Phone1>
        <Phone2>9876543215</Phone2>
        <Email>amrit@gmail.com</Email>
        <DOB>20-05-2016</DOB>
        <Age>26</Age>
        <Child_DOB>20-05-2002</Child_DOB>
        <Child_Age>4</Child_Age>
        <Pincode>400052</Pincode>
        <City_Name>Mumbai</City_Name>
        <Address>2, Akshardham…..</Address>
        <Annual_Income>1000000</Annual_Income>
        <Annual_Income_Slab>10</Annual_Income_Slab>
        <SMS_Keyword>0</SMS_Keyword>
        <Short_Code></Short_Code>
        <Circle_Operator></Circle_Operator>
        <Sum_Assured></Sum_Assured>
        <Premium_Pitched></Premium_Pitched>
        <Company_Name>WRS</Company_Name>
         <Website_Name>Bima Deals.com</Website_Name>
         <UTN_Source>FaceBook</UTN_Source>
         <Lead_Source></Lead_Source>
         <Type_Of_Lead></Type_Of_Lead>
         <Verification_Type></Verification_Type>
         <Product_Name></Product_Name>
         <Product_Category></Product_Category>
         <No_of_Companies></No_of_Companies>
         <Names_of_Companied></Names_of_Companied>
         <SMS_Message_Sent></SMS_Message_Sent>
         <Customer__Remarks></Customer__Remarks>
         <FLAG></FLAG>
         <Lead_Type>INCOMING_WEB</Lead_Type>
         <Channel_Type>INTERNET</Channel_Type>
         <Mode_Type>PREFIXED_APPOINTMENT</Mode_Type>
         <Source_Type>BIMADEALS</Source_Type>
         <Campaign_Type>APR_16</Campaign_Type>
         <Opportunity_Id>123456</Opportunity_Id>
         <PROSPECT_ID></PROSPECT_ID>
         <Title>MR</Title>
         <UID></UID>
         <LastName>Lastname</LastName>
         <Gender>Male</Gender>
         <MaritalStatus></MaritalStatus>
         <MobileNo>9865856325</MobileNo>
         <AgeAtRetirement></AgeAtRetirement>
         <VendorCSE_Name></VendorCSE_Name>
         <TermOfPlan></TermOfPlan>
         <Smoker_NonSmoker></Smoker_NonSmoker>
         <VendorCode></VendorCode>
         <MeetingDate></MeetingDate>
         <MeetingTime></MeetingTime>
         <City_ID>67</City_ID>
         <ID>123</ID>
         <CallcenterID></CallcenterID>
         <ADDLInfo1></ADDLInfo1>
         <ADDLInfo2></ADDLInfo2>
         </RBSS>
         </PushData>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: I have fixed the formatting because your XML-code was invisible

Comment: Hi Thomas, may i know what was the formatting error i had, please post the code here...... let me learn, i tried to run the same code and getting, XML Foramt error ( Object reference not set to an instance of an object. )  on online SOAP Client,   https://wsdlbrowser.com

Comment: Hi Raja, you missed to indent your XML code in the question by 4 characters. Cllick the [edited 2 days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52235666/revisions) link to see the difference.

Comment: Raja, you may also want to read [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: thank you Thomas i got it, when i try to run the code in online soap client " https://wsdlbrowser.com ", i am getting, FAIL : XML Foramt error ( Object reference not set to an instance of an object. )